# Excel Formula to Lookup multiple columns

Tags: excel

I tried reading other questions on this matter, and everything is very specific to that person so it got pretty confusing...

Anyways, I was looking for a way to use VLOOKUP or Index Match to do the following (I've been trying but I keep running into errors or weird...long....formulas...):

I have 2 excel Sheets. One excel sheet has something like this:

[image: Sheet1]

(This is incomplete. I haven't put in prices yet, but I'm working on the formatting and formulas foremost. Just pretend there are prices in those empty cells :) )

The second excel sheet is this:

[image: Sheet2]

In the 2nd Sheet, F Column, I was trying to get a formula to match Sheet2ColumnE with Sheet1 Columns A,F,K,P,U & Z and return [depending on whether cell D is B or S] the single or bulk price for the specific item.

I've used the Index Match formula before, but it got tricky when I had to index multiple columns and match multiple columns. Is there a simple way to get this going? Or will I be looping IFs?

Thanks for assistance.

Here is the workbook. Or a sample of it...

[Test.xml](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XV7Ep3G1eVPXzPkv-PBdzYANqGQmpoXi0v5oABjya1w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I would be a bit upset with whoever designed the first sheet and the veggies in `K5` :] You can use something like IfError( Index+Match, IfError( Index+Match ..), 0 ). If there are no repeating item names, you can probably use just one `SumProduct` function

Comment: Can you change the first spreadsheet? I would flatten it down into a single table (rather than multiple tables that are side by side) and then use a pivot table instead. If you can modify the original, then please attach the file or provide a place to download it and I can show you what I mean.

The columns would be: 

Item, Group, Single Price, Price by Bulk

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. I've attached a copy of the workbook. I might have to just run it down one table. I had it this way so I could print it, but I'll just change it. Workarounds, I guess.